# Store multiple values to a specific user SQLITE

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm attempting to let a user which is logged into my flask website, enter a form which outputs an integer, and then they can then view all their output from the form in their profile.

I was thinking that when the user enters out the form, it creates a new table for that specific user and enters the results into that table would that work?

Comment: It probably makes more sense to have a users table, and when a user is logged in to show only the row(s) in that table associated to that particular user.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I generate sqlite3 tables dynamically on the fly, if you do go that route:

```
def create_table(ptbl):

    """ Assemble DDL (Data Definition Language) Table Create statement and build
        sqlite3 db table

    Args:
        string: new db table name.

    Returns:
        Status string, '' or 'SUCCESS'.
    """
    retval = ''
    sqlCmd = ''
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
        c = conn.cursor()

        if ptbl == 'TBL_EXAMPLE':
            sqlCmd = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + ptbl + ' (FIELD1 TEXT, FIELD2 INTEGER, FIELD3 TEXT, ' \
                                                            'FIELD4 TEXT, FIELD5 TEXT)'
        else:
            pass

        if sqlCmd != '':
            c.execute(sqlCmd)
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()

        retval = 'SUCCESS'

    except Error as e:

        retval = 'FAIL'
        print(e)

    return retval
```